# Navigating my React-Router app in URL - How to Update Redux State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am making a React Website with a rest countries API.
My routing is simple, you need to pass through every page, to navigate to the end, where the url will look something like "localhost:3000/**countries**/**Canada**/**Toronto**".

```
 <Route path="/" index element={<Home />} />
 <Route path="/countries" element={<AllCountries />} />
 <Route path="/countries/:countryName" element={<SingleCountry />} />
 <Route path="/countries/:countryName/:city" element={<City />} />
```

Now, on the **AllCountries** Component, a useEffect will dispatch an API call, save the data in store. Upon choosing a country, the appropriate Object for that country is also saved in the store and the user will then continue to /countries/:countryChosen or the **SingleCountry** Component where the user will now choose a city, and more data will be passed to /countries/:countryChosen/:cityChosen.

No issues so far, however, if I was to manually navigate through the URL bar to /countries/France/Paris -- none of my state is in the store, because of course I did not navigate the site and my dispatches did not go off.

I managed to fix this issue in the **SingleCountry** component (If the user skipped AllCountries) by adding a useEffect, and fetching the countries API if the data is not present in store. However, I am faced with the same problem in the **City** Component, and would need several dispatches on initial render of the component to solve this, and figured it's time for a more robust solution.

Comment: From what I gather, looks like you're fetching absolutely everything right from the start when accessing /countries, then just navigate through the data. "I managed to fix this issue in the SingleCountry component (If the user skipped AllCountries) by adding a useEffect, and fetching the countries API if the data is not present in store" Again, fetching everything?! What does your API look like? Can't you fetch the data for a specific country only when accessing it ?

Comment: Also, why do you need a store?

Comment: @jperl lol, I don't think I do, but the purpose of this project is to learn redux. I realize now it doesn't need it. Ok but if I was to manually navigate to /countries/France/Paris, how would I go about fetching the correct data, how would I dynamically populate the app with the correct data?

Comment: I am fetching the API in /countries, then passing the country selected to /countryName, which uses the API as well as local data based on the country selected. Then depending on the city picked, I am passing that city name to City component, and displaying more content

Comment: Just an update, I used { useLocation } from react-router to parse the url, grabbed the city: string, iterated over the data to find the correct Obj, then stored it. Now, despite the poor use of redux in an app that doesn't need it, would parsing the url in this way be considered bad practice?